# get_post_meta and add_post_meta not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying a simple test in wordpress using `add_post_meta` and `get_post_meta` but is not working. I'm trying this code:

```
function test_post_meta($postID) {
    $count_key = 'test';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '1');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
    var_dump($count);
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    var_dump($count);
    update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
}
```

The result is:

**bool(false) bool(false)**

I'm expecting 1- 1, 2-2 and so on on every call from my function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Is there nothing at all saved in the database? Have you tried using another value than `test`? Also make sure the `$postID` value is actually given and is an existing post.

You can also check the result of `update_post_meta`, check the [WordPress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) for the expected result.

I optimised your code a bit:

```
function test_post_meta($postID) {
    $count_key = 'test';
    $count = (int)get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true) ?: 1;

    $count++;
    update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);


    var_dump($count);
    var_dump(get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true));
}
```